# Return enum object using validate method inside list validate function

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a problem that I want to resolve with Java streams if possible. This is my code.

```
class Foo {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    // getters and setters
}

enum FooError {
    NO_NAME("Name cannot be null."), NO_SURNAME("Surname cannot be null");

    private final String message;

    FooError(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String message() {
        return message;
    }

}

public FooError validate(final Foo foo) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(foo.getName())) {
        return FooError.NO_NAME;
    }

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(foo.getSurname())) {
        return FooError.NO_SURNAME;
    }
    return null;
}

public FooError validateFooList(final List<Foo> fooList) {
    FooError = fooList.stream()....
}
```

I want to return the first FooError ocurrence or null in the list using streams. Is it possible and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: `fooList.stream().map(this::validate).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null)`. The `map` operation gives a `Stream<FooError>` with possible `null` values, so these need to be filtered out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public FooError validateFooList(final List<Foo> fooList) {
    return fooList.stream()
            .map(this::validate)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    }
```

This calls the `validate` method for each `Foo` instance and filters  only the non-null `FooError` values, finds and returns the first `FooError` in the stream or *null* if there are none.